# Quiero llenar varios SELECT de diferentes bases de datos en MySQL al cargar mi pagina

Tags: mysql, nodejs, express

Intento llenar varios SELECT de diferentes bases de datos en MySQL al cargar mi pagina.

Tengo mi modelo, controlador y rutas definido para cada tabla en MySQL que trabajan bien.. con NODE JS.

Tablas desde donde requiero la información, ejem: Figura, Materias y Clientes. (es un proyecto para abogados.. Figura="Demandado" y "Actor"; Materias="Familiar" y "Laboral"; Clientes="Nombre" y "Apellidos"...)

Saludos cordiales.

Comment: Que tal amigo, podrias ser un poco mas especifico de cual es tu problema. gracias

Comment: ¿Como lo has intentando?  No veo el error ni como lo has intentando

Comment: Muestra el código _como texto, con formato_ y explica qué problema(s) has tenido: lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Amigos todos.

Espero se encuentren bien.

Una disculpa, porque estoy iniciando en este foro y entendiendo como trabaja.. además nuevo en HTML5, MySQL, Node JS, Express, Java, Sass, layout, EJS y CSS.

Indagando en la web he logrado construir una aplicación web bajo el concepto MVC.

Con lo que tengo ya trabajando (mis rutas, controladores, modelos y vistas).

Como le puedo hacer para que al cargar una págína HTML llene varios SELECT de diferentes tablas que almacena la base de datos en MySQL.

He checado en la web y hasta el momento los ejemplos que comparten (gracias). Crean una función y la ejecutan al iniciar el documento HTML (los datos los capturan en el código).

Lo que trate de preguntar es:

Se puede ejecutar una de las rutas para que mediante el controlador y modelos extraer los datos y crear el objeto de X tabla y entonces colocar los datos en el SELECT mediante un forEach.
El detalle es que necesito lo mismo para varias tablas: Clientes, Figura, Materia, etc.

El forEach por ejemplo, lo utilizo al cargar la pantalla de inicio de cada módulo (servicios, clientes, empresa, usuarios, asesorías, litigios, catálogos varios, etc.)

```
<body>
<div class="forma-main forma-main-large">
<div class="contenedor-forma">

<div class="titulo-forma">
<p class="titulo titulo-1"> Solicitud de servicio </p>
</div> 
        
<div class="encabezado-forma">
<div class="botones-header-forma">
<a href="/servicios/create" class="btn btn-encabezado btn-encabezado-agrega"> <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> </a>
<a href="/servicios" class="btn btn-encabezado btn-encabezado-imprimir"> <i class="fas fa-print"></i> </a>
<a href="/" class="btn btn-encabezado btn-encabezado-salida"> <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> </a>
</div>

<div class="filter-header-forma">
<input type="text" class="filter" id="filter" placeholder="Filtrar datos..." onkeyup="searchTablaMain()">
</div>
</div>

<table id="tabla-main"  class="tabla-borde">
<thead>
<tr class="tabla-columna-titulo">
<th scope="col">núm</th>
<th scope="col">rfc</th>
<th scope="col">razónSocial</th>
<th scope="col">nomComercial</th>
<th scope="col">figura</th>
<th scope="col">materia</th>
<th scope="col">asunto</th>
<th scope="col">archDocBase</th>
<th scope="col">archDemanda</th>
<th scope="col">archFijacionLitis</th>
<th scope="col">estatus</th>
<th scope="col">fecha</th>
<th scope="col">nCliente</th>
<th scope="col">acciones</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<% servicios.forEach((servicios)=> { %>
<tr>
<td> <%= servicios.nServicio %> </td>
<td> <%= servicios.rfc %> </td>
<td> <%= servicios.razonSocial %> </td>
<td> <%= servicios.nomComercial %> </td>
<td> <%= servicios.figura %> </td>
<td> <%= servicios.materia %> </td>
<td> <%= servicios.descripcionAsunto %> </td>
<td> <%= servicios.archivoDocBase %> </td>
<td> <%= servicios.archivoDemanda %> </td>
<td> <%= servicios.archivoFijacionLitis %> </td>
<td> <%= servicios.analisis_estatus %> </td>
<td> <%= servicios.fecha %> </td>
<td> <%= servicios.Clientes_nCliente %> </td>
<td>
<div class="btns-linea-tabla">
<a href="/servicios/<%= servicios.nServicio %>" class="btn btn-linea-tabla btn-tabla-edit"> <i class="far fa-edit"></i> </a>
<a href="/servicios/delete/<%= servicios.nServicio %>" class="btn btn-linea-tabla btn-tabla-borrar"> <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i> </a>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<% }) %>
</tbody>
<tfoot></tfoot>
</table> 

<div class="piePagina-forma"></div>
</div> 
</div>
</body>
```

Este es el ejemplo de como lleno los SELECT en la pantalla de captura de nuevos registros:

```
<body>
<form class="forma-main forma-main-medium" action="/servicios/" method="POST">
<div class="contenedor-forma">

<div class="titulo-forma">
<p class="titulo titulo-1"> Solicitud de servicio | Agregar </p>
</div> 
    
<div class="encabezado-forma">
<div class="botones-header-forma">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-encabezado btn-encabezado-grabar"> <i class="fas fa-check"></i> </button>
<a href="/servicios" class="btn btn-encabezado btn-encabezado-salida"> <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> </a>                    
</div>               
</div>
    
<div class="captura-forma">
<div class="captura-seccion captura-seccion-1" hidden>
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="nServicio" maxlength="20" id="nServicio" name="nServicio" type="text" disabled=true size="5">
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="nUsuario" maxlength="20" id="nUsuario" name="nUsuario" type="text" value="1" size="5">
<label>Requiere factura
<select class="captura-txt" placeholder="requiereFactura"  id="requiereFactura" name="requiereFactura">
<option value="Sí"> Sí </option>
<option value="No" selected> No </option>
</select>
</label>
</div>
<div class="captura-seccion captura-seccion-2">
<label>Figura 
<select class="captura-txt" placeholder="nFigura"  id="nFigura" name="nFigura">
<option value="1" selected>Actor</option>
<option value="2">Demandado</option>
<option value="3">Tercero</option>
<option value="4">Promovente</option>
</select>               
</label>                    
<label>Materia 
<select class="captura-txt" placeholder="nMateria"  id="nMateria" name="nMateria">                            
<option value="1" selected>Familiar</option>
<option value="2">Civil</option>
<option value="3">Laboral</option>
<option value="4">Mercantil</option>
</select>
</label>                    
<br>
<textarea class="captura-txt" cols=135 id="descripcionAsunto" maxlength="500" name="descripcionAsunto"  placeholder="descripcionAsunto" rows=5></textarea>
<br>
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="archivoDocBase" maxlength="100" id="archivoDocBase" name="archivoDocBase" type="text">
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="archivoDemanda" maxlength="100" id="archivoDemanda" name="archivoDemanda" type="text">
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="archivoFijacionLitis" maxlength="100" id="archivoFijacionLitis" name="archivoFijacionLitis" type="text">
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="archivoSentencia" maxlength="100" id="archivoSentencia" name="archivoSentencia" type="text">
<label>fecha registro
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="fecha" maxlength="45" id="fecha" name="fecha" type="date" value="2022-01-01"  min="2022-01-01" max="2030-12-31">
</label>                
</div>
<div class="captura-seccion captura-seccion-3">                        
<label>Datos contacto parte contraria</label>
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="nombre" maxlength="100" id="contacto_nombre" name="contacto_nombre" type="text" size=45>
<br>
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="calle" maxlength="100" id="contacto_calle" name="contacto_calle" type="text" size=45>
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="nInterior" maxlength="20" id="contacto_nInterior" name="contacto_nInterior" type="text" size=2>
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="nExterior" maxlength="20" id="contacto_nExterior" name="contacto_nExterior" type="text" size=2>
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="colonia" maxlength="45" id="contacto_colonia" name="contacto_colonia" type="text">
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="cp" maxlength="5" id="contacto_cp" name="contacto_cp" type="text" size=2>
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="localidad" maxlength="45" id="contacto_localidad" name="contacto_localidad" type="text">
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="municipio" maxlength="45" id="contacto_municipio" name="contacto_municipio" type="text">
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="estado" maxlength="45" id="contacto_estado" name="contacto_estado" type="text">
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="pais" maxlength="45" id="contacto_pais" name="contacto_pais" type="text" size=9>
<br>
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="teléfono1 (123-123-1234)" maxlength="20" id="contacto_telefono1" name="contacto_telefono1" type="text">
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="teléfono2 (123-123-1234)" maxlength="20" id="contacto_telefono2" name="contacto_telefono2" type="text">
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="celular1 (123-123-1234)" maxlength="20" id="contacto_celular1" name="contacto_celular1" type="text">
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="celular2 (123-123-1234)" maxlength="20" id="contacto_celular2" name="contacto_celular2" type="text">
<br>
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="correo@electronico1.com" maxlength="100" id="contacto_correoElectronico1" name="contacto_correoElectronico1" type="email">
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="correo@electronico2.com" maxlength="100" id="contacto_correoElectronico2" name="contacto_correoElectronico2" type="email">
</div>
<div class="captura-seccion captura-seccion-4">
<label>Abogado asignado</label>
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="titulo" maxlength="45" id="abogado_titulo" name="abogado_titulo" type="text" size=2>
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="nombre" maxlength="100" id="abogado_nombre" name="abogado_nombre" type="text" size=45>
<br>
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="calle" maxlength="100" id="abogado_calle" name="abogado_calle" type="text" size=45>
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="nInterior" maxlength="20" id="abogado_nInterior" name="abogado_nInterior" type="text" size=2>
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="nExterior" maxlength="20" id="abogado_nExterior" name="abogado_nExterior" type="text" size=2>
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="colonia" maxlength="45" id="abogado_colonia" name="abogado_colonia" type="text">
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="cp" maxlength="5" id="abogado_cp" name="abogado_cp" type="text" size=2>
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="localidad" maxlength="45" id="abogado_localidad" name="abogado_localidad" type="text">
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="municipio" maxlength="45" id="abogado_municipio" name="abogado_municipio" type="text">
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="estado" maxlength="45" id="abogado_estado" name="abogado_estado" type="text">
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="pais" maxlength="45" id="abogado_pais" name="abogado_pais" type="text" size=9>
<br>
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="teléfono1 (123-123-1234)" maxlength="20" id="abogado_telefono1" name="abogado_telefono1" type="text">
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="teléfono2 (123-123-1234)" maxlength="20" id="abogado_telefono2" name="abogado_telefono2" type="text">
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="celular1 (123-123-1234)" maxlength="20" id="abogado_celular1" name="abogado_celular1" type="text">
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="celular2 (123-123-1234)" maxlength="20" id="abogado_celular2" name="abogado_celular2" type="text">
<br>
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="correo@electronico1.com" maxlength="100" id="abogado_correoElectronico1" name="abogado_correoElectronico1" type="email">
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="correo@electronico2.com" maxlength="100" id="abogado_correoElectronico2" name="abogado_correoElectronico2" type="email">
</div>
<div class="captura-seccion captura-seccion-5" hidden>
<label>Datos comerciales</label>
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="fechaFactura" maxlength="45" id="dComerciales_fechaFactura" name="dComerciales_fechaFactura" type="date" value="2022-01-01"  min="2022-01-01" max="2030-12-31">
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="factura" maxlength="20" id="dComerciales_factura" name="dComerciales_factura" type="number" value=0>
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="uuid" maxlength="36" id="dComerciales_uuid" name="dComerciales_uuid" type="text">
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="monto" maxlength="20" id="dComerciales_monto" name="dComerciales_monto" type="number" value=0>
<label>Estatus de la factura
<select class="captura-txt" placeholder="estatus"  id="dComerciales_estatus" name="dComerciales_estatus">                            
<option value="1">Pagado</option>
<option value="2">Cancelado</option>
<option value="3" selected>CxC</option>
</select>
</label>                    
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="formaPagoFactura" maxlength="2" id="dComerciales_formaPagoFactura" name="dComerciales_formaPagoFactura" type="text">
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="fechaPago" maxlength="45" id="dComerciales_fechaPago" name="dComerciales_fechaPago" type="date" value="2022-01-01"  min="2022-01-01" max="2030-12-31">
</div>
<div class="captura-seccion captura-seccion-6" hidden>
<label>Cliente
<select class="captura-txt" placeholder="Clientes_nCliente"  id="Clientes_nCliente" name="Clientes_nCliente">
<option value="3" selected>Cliente_3</option>
<option value="8">Cliente_8</option>
</select>
</label>                    
<label>Régimen fiscal
<select class="captura-txt" placeholder="Clientes_Regimen_nRegimen"  id="Clientes_Regimen_nRegimen" name="Clientes_Regimen_nRegimen">                            
<option value="1" selected>Personas Físicas con Actividades Empresariales y Profesionales</option>
<option value="2">General de Ley Personas Morales</option>
</select>
</label>                    
</div>
<div class="captura-seccion captura-seccion-7" hidden>
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="analisis_procede" maxlength="2" id="analisis_procede" name="analisis_procede" type="text">
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="analisis_descripcion" maxlength="500" id="analisis_descripcion" name="analisis_descripcion" type="text">
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="analisis_analista" maxlength="20" id="analisis_analista" name="analisis_analista" type="number" value=1>
<label>Estatus petición de servicio
<select class="captura-txt" placeholder="analisis_estatus"  id="analisis_estatus" name="analisis_estatus">                            
<option value="Analisis" selected>Análisis</option>
<option value="NoProcede">No procede</option>
<option value="Procede">Procede</option>
</select>
</label>                    
<input class="captura-txt" placeholder="analisis_fecha" maxlength="45" id="analisis_fecha" name="analisis_fecha" type="date" value="2022-01-01"  min="2022-01-01" max="2030-12-31">
</div>
</div>
        
<div class="piePagina-forma"></div>
</div> 
</form>
</body>
```

Este es el ejemplo del controlador que es el encargado de entregar datos y renderizar la vista (pansado por el modelo):

```
readAll1: async(req, res, next) =>{
try {
const [figuras, _] = await Figuras.readAll()

res.status(200).json({ count: figuras.length, figuras })
//res.render('xgp_catFigura', {figuras:figuras})
} catch (error) {
console.log(error)
//next(error)            
}
},
```

Este código del el modelo:

```
static readAll() {
let sql = ("SELECT * FROM catalogoFigura")
return db.execute(sql)
}
```

Sin más por el momento, gracias.

Saludos cordiales.

Comment: La zona de respuestas no es para comentarios, ni para nuevas preguntas. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Por otra parte, los saludos y agradecimientos [tampoco](/help/behavior) [son necesarios](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4283). _Se agradece votando a favor_. Por último: ¿perdiste tu cuenta anterior? Podés solicitar [combinar/fusionar tus cuentas](/contact).

Comment: Para hacer lo que has hecho lo más correcto es editar tu pregunta añadiendo está información.

Comment: Perdiste el acceso a tu cuenta? cual es la cuenta que sirve?

Comment: Cuando pregunte por primera vez fue como invitado con Hércules Palacios (hercules.palacios@hotmail.com) y después me dí de alta como HerPal, (más corto) mismo correo.. y agregue comentarios pero  arriba me indican que tengo dos cuentas... quise combinar pero nada... he cometido errores.. la cuenta que me gustaría que quedará sería como: HerPal correo hercules.palacios@hotmail.com..